# getting IllegalArgumentException when trying to create key for entity

Tags: java, google-app-engine, key

I'm working on Google App Engine and I'm stuck at a point. I'm trying to create a key for my entity. Here is the code:

```
Element child = (Element) itr.next();
                String name = "";
                if(child.getQualifiedName().equals("name")){
                    name += child.getText();
                }
                Key drugKey = KeyFactory.createKey("DrugTarget", name);
```

I'm 100% sure that child.getText() doesn't return null. I tested it already. I have another piece of code that creating Key works perfectly. Both seem similar to each other.

```
String drug = req.getParameter("drugname");
Key drugKey = KeyFactory.createKey("DrugTarget", drug);
```

I really did'nt understand why it gives error. First piece of code is belonged to a Java Class and I call this class in a Java Servlet Class. The second one is belonged to a Java Servlet Class. But I think the problem is different. Could you please help? Thanks.

Edited Part:

```
if(child.getQualifiedName().equals("name")){
                    if(child.getText() != null){
                    name = child.getText();
                    }
                    else{
                        name = "asd";
                    }
                }
```

I put this into my code, still getting null error. child.getText() does not return null and name is not equal to "asd".

Forgot to add Error Message:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name cannot be null or empty
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory.createKey(KeyFactory.java:73)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory.createKey(KeyFactory.java:60)
at guestbook.saxParser2.getDrug(saxParser2.java:42)
at guestbook.SignGuestbookServlet.doPost(SignGuestbookServlet.java:77)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:102)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:447)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: What is the point of using `name+=child.getText();` , i cant see any loops aswell when it might have made some sense? Why not just `name=child.getText();`

Comment: Full stack trace please?

Comment: I also tried to use  name=child.getText(); but still getting same error

Comment: Is that piece of code inside a loop?

Comment: yes it is in a while loop and I create this key for each name

Comment: So you are getting a null for an iteration. Did u debug each iteration? I think a nullcheck `if(child.getText!=null)` and enclosing the current if block and the key formation in it.

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't enter null condition

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message said:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name cannot be null or empty
```

And your actual code:

```
String name = "";
if(child.getQualifiedName().equals("name")){
  name += child.getText();
}
Key drugKey = KeyFactory.createKey("DrugTarget", name);
```

So in the if statement the `child.getQualifiedName().equals("name")` expression is false, and the 'name' String variable is still an empty String (`String name = ""`).
And that is what the error message said: cannot be an empty String at `Key drugKey = KeyFactory.createKey("DrugTarget", name);` as parameter.

EDIT:
Try out this:

```
Element child = (Element) itr.next();
String name = "defaultName";
if(child.getQualifiedName().equals("name")){
  name = child.getText();
}
Key drugKey = KeyFactory.createKey("DrugTarget", name);
```

The problem isn't that the `child.getText()` return with null or not, the problem is the expression at your if statement will be `false`, so the `name += child.getText();` is unreachable and the `name` still an empty String.

```
if(child.getQualifiedName().equals("name")){
      name += child.getText();
}
```

Comment: I editied my code. Could you check it please. I tried same way in another file. I'm 100% sure that child.getText() doesn't return null. It returns a string.

Comment: @AhmetTanakol its not about .getText being null. Its about `if(child.getQualifiedName().equals("name"))` being false. and thus `name` does not get modified, stays n empty string and the `createKey()` is called with empty string. Hence the error.

Comment: I tested child.getQualifiedName().equals("name")) many times. It works perfectly. I'm using the same code without putting entries into datastore. When I try to create entries and put them into datastore, it started to give error.

Comment: @AhmetTanakol That's probably because the Datastore threw the Exception when you tried put some Entities into.

Comment: @AhmetTanakol You still have any problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

"cooke up"  ready to eat.

```
Element child = (Element) itr.next();
                String name;
                if(child.getQualifiedName().equals("name")){
                    name = child.getText();
                 if(name!=null){
                    Key drugKey = KeyFactory.createKey("DrugTarget", name);
                 }
                }
```